# Digit dial during phone call - Android

Tags: android, phone-call

Is it possible to dial a digit during a phone call via code?

After having started a phone call by an app of course.
For example:

```
String uri = "tel:999999999";
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
intent.setData(Uri.parse(uri));
startActivity(intent);
```

And now I want to dial some numbers during the call, is it even possible?

Comment: Did you had any progress in here?

Comment: It's possible to program a sequence of numbers that will be dialed after making the calls, and code the exact time when that will happen.

Comment: Sounds great! I've found no sample of this. Did you? Can you share   any piece of code?

Comment: String uri = "tel: 999999999,,,,,,,,,,2,,1";
   Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
   intent.setData(Uri.parse(uri));
   startActivity(intent);

The , is a break of some seconds I dont remember how many, you gotta test it